# Using sed to insert text at end of line matching string

Tags: bash, sed

I have a line in a text file containing a list of items assigned to a variable ...

```
ITEMS="$ITEM1 $ITEM2 $ITEM3"
```

And I would like write a bash script that uses sed to find the line matching ITEMS and append another item to the end of the list within the double quotes, so it results in ...

```
ITEMS="$ITEM1 $ITEM2 $ITEM3 $ITEM4"
```

Furthermore, I have the number of the item to add stored in a variable, let's say it's $number.  So I'm trying to get it to add $ITEM4$number and have it replace $number with whatever I assigned to that variable, let's say it's the number 4 in this case.  How could I best accomplish this?  Thanks!

Comment: Something like this: `sed -i 's/$ITEMS$/$ITEMS ITEM4/g' filename` ?

Comment: 1) is the name "ITEM1-3" known or dynamic? 2) is the number of elements in your list known( fixed 3) or dynamic?

Comment: The name of the last item in the list is not known.  I simply want to add the content before the last double quote.

Comment: The number of elements is also dynamic.

Comment: -1 for changing your question too much times and [cross-posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560240/using-sed-to-insert-text-with-variable-at-end-of-line-matching-string)  at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat file
ITEMS="$ITEM1 $ITEM2 $ITEM3"
$ number=4
$ sed "/ITEMS/s/\"$/ \$ITEM$number&/" file
ITEMS="$ITEM1 $ITEM2 $ITEM3 $ITEM4"
```

Comment: Thanks Ed.  You and sputnick are life savers.

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
num=4
sed "/ITEMS=/s/\"$/ \$ITEM${num}\"/"
```

### Explanations

- the sed form used here is `/re/s/before/after/` where `re` is a regex (like a `grep`), `s///` is *substitution*
- `\s` is a space and `*` mean 0 ore more occurence(s)
- `&` stands for the string matched in the left part of the *substitution*
- `^` as first character of a regex means *start of string/line*
- `$` as last character of a regex means *end of string/line*

Comment: Thanks!  How would it change if the items had $ in front of them so it would be `ITEMS="$ITEM1 $ITEM2 $ITEM3 $ITEM4"`?

Comment: `sed '/^\s*ITEMS=/s/"$$/$ITEM4$"/' file`

Comment: See my last explanation in my post

Comment: Thank you very much.  Excellent explanations.  I'm still trying to get it to print a given number stored in a a variable for the item added though and I'm having trouble getting it to print the number.  Ultimately, I want it to add `$ITEM$number`, where I have assigned `$number` elsewhere (lets say it's 4 in this case), and have it add `$ITEM4` substituting `$number` in properly. What would we have to change to do that?