# insert text with sed on the same line that pattern search

Tags: sed

For example if I have this file :

```
The green horse is blue localhost
my pants is dirty localhost
your eyes is so beautiful localhost
The best area is localhost
```

And I want to add text (192.168.25.50) in this file after each 'localhost' pattern search.

- I don't want to create a new line
- I don't want to insert on **each end of line but just after a pattern**
- I don't want to use awk, I need to know if sed command can do this

Indeed my result must look like that :

```
The green horse is blue localhost 192.168.25.50
my pants is dirty localhost 192.168.25.50
your eyes is so beautiful localhost 192.168.25.50
The best area is localhost 192.168.25.50
```

Lot of sed issue exist but all have a specific context which can't help my simple and basics issue. I already can insert text after a pattern in a same file but never in a same line.

**Can you explain me how to insert with sed command in a same line that the pattern used by sed command itself ?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using sed to insert text at end of line matching string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559821/using-sed-to-insert-text-at-end-of-line-matching-string)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/\blocalhost\b/& 192.168.25.50/' file
```

---

> `\b`: a zero-width word boundary
>
> `&`:  refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.